why mapping of array not work same ad mapping record?
is there a reason why mapping an array does not work the same way as mapping a record?
An array is, in itself, an iterable object just like a Record<number, ...>, right ?
In this code, you can observe the desired behavior for ParamRecordRecord.
This gives me a data table with methods that have a parameter automatically inferred based on the data context.
I also need a version in the form of a record for arrays.
ParamRecordArray is therefore an exact copy of ParamRecordRecord, except that instead of having keys enumerated in enum BBB, the keys are the array indices.
However, for some reason, I cannot reproduce the same behavior as the table above.
All parameters in the methods components are numbers.
a mark in red where the issue occur
enum AAA { a1 = 'a1', a2 = 'a2', a3 = 'a3' }
enum BBB { b1 = 'b1', b2 = 'b2', b3 = 'b3' }

// the data structure
type TestData<T extends number = number> = {
    _: string;
    components?: T[];
    check: (c: T) => void;
}

// version record of record

type ParamRecordRecord<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T & AAA]: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA] & BBB]?: TestData<Extract<T[KA][KB], number> extends never ? number : Extract<T[KA][KB], number>>
    }
}

new class TestRecorRecord<T> {
    constructor(data: ParamRecordRecord<T>) { }
}(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: {
            [BBB.b1]: {
                _: '',
                check: (c) => { } //number
                //     ^?
            },
        },
        [AAA.a2]: {
            [BBB.b2]: {
                _: '',
                components: [1],
                check: (c) => { }//1
                //     ^?
            },
            [BBB.b1]: {
                _: '',
                components: [2],
                check: (c) => { }//2
                //     ^?
            },
        },
    }
)



// version record of array

//This is a copy of ParamRecordRecord, except that the iteration is done over the index of the object array.
//The index keys are numbers or `${number}`, rather than strings coming from the BBB enumerator.
type ParamRecordArray<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T & AAA]: {
        [KB in keyof T[KA] & `${number}`]?: TestData<Extract<T[KA][KB], number> extends never ? number : Extract<T[KA][KB], number>>
    }
}

new class TestRecorArray<T> {
    constructor(data: ParamRecordArray<T>) { }
}(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: [
            {
                _: '',
                check: (c) => { }//number
                //     ^?
            },
        ],
        [AAA.a2]: [
            {
                _: '',
                components: [1],
                check: (c) => { }//1
                //     ^?
            },
            {
                _: '',
                components: [2],
                check: (c) => { }//2
                //     ^?
            },
        ],
    }
)


//ok not work so let try debug ?
type debug = ParamRecordArray<{ [AAA.a1]: [ TestData<1>, TestData<2> ] }>
//   ^?
// ya it seem not able to extract the generic , but am not understand why !?

playground
Thank you in advance for your clarification and for a solution if possible.
NOTE: i dont want use as const or a function<const T>():T everywhere for each entries just for array versions.
const T in the class can be a solution but seem not work !
I also could have used a single wrapper, but the const T type doesn't seem to handle nested Record<string, TestData[]> in this case.

I'd say your problem here is that mapped types over arrays only behave homomorphically when the array type is directly generic, so if you refactor like this playground link shows, then it should start working as expected. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Wow, yes, this exactly matches the behavior I was hoping for!
It's fascinating, thank you for the solution.
I had eventually resigned myself to putting as const everywhere! It was unbearable !

I’ll write an answer when I get a chance.

Thank you. I suppose this is related to the fact that sometimes it’s necessary to separate types because they can behave differently. A colleague once told me: “Sometimes second-level mapped types behave differently from first-level types, and it’s better to separate them into a new generic type.”

note that your debugging line should look like type debug = ParamRecordArray<{ [AAA.a1]: [1, 2] }> not type debug = ParamRecordArray<{ [AAA.a1]: [ TestData<1>, TestData<2> ] }>

You've run into a longstanding bug reported at microsoft/TypeScript#27995 where mapped types over array and tuple types don't quite behave like homomorphic mapped types (see What does "homomorphic mapped type" mean?) unless the type being mapped over is a generic type parameter.  If T is a generic type parameter, then {[K in keyof T]: F<T[K]>} will map array types to array types and tuple types to tuple types. But otherwise it will map over all the keys of the array type including things like "length" and "push". Homomorphic mapped types allow for inference of T from a value of type {[K in keyof T]: F<T[K]>}, and this sort of inference is what you need for your code to work. It isn't happening, so you're getting bad inference.
This is considered a bug but it's not clear when or if it will ever be fixed. Until and unless that happens, you can work around it by just refactoring so that the type being mapped over is a generic type parameter; that is, make a utility type:
type ParamRecordArray<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T & AAA]: F<T[KA]>
}

type F<T> = { [KB in keyof T]?: TestData<
    Extract<T[KB], number> extends never ? number : Extract<T[KB], number>
> }

Here F<T[KA]> is doing what your original { [KB in keyof T[KA] & ${number}]?: ⋯ } was doing. Note that there's no reason to intersect with `${number}` since all that will do is break the homomorphic mapping and prevent the inference you need, and homomorphic mapped array/tuples already only iterate over the numeric-like indices.
Let's make sure it works:
const z = new class TestRecorArray<T> {
    constructor(data: ParamRecordArray<T>) { }
}(
    {
        [AAA.a1]: [
            {
                _: '',
                check: (c) => { }//number
                //     ^? (parameter) c: number
            },
        ],
        [AAA.a2]: [
            {
                _: '',
                components: [1],
                check: (c) => { }//1
                //     ^? (parameter) c: 1
            },
            {
                _: '',
                components: [2],
                check: (c) => { }//2
                //     ^? (parameter) c: 2
            },
        ],
    }
)

Looks good!
Playground link to code

The explanation is very clear and I understand it. Thank you for your time quality, you’re awesome.

The problem is because TypeScript with arrays and types Arrays use numbers as keys and TypeScript has trouble guessing the right type for each item.
so to fix it use a helper type to grab the type inside the array. this will help the TS understand what type should expect.
type ArrayElement<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never;

type ParamRecordArray<T> = {
    [KA in keyof T & AAA]: T[KA] extends readonly any[] ? {
        [KB in keyof T[KA] & `${number}`]?: TestData<ArrayElement<T[KA]> extends number ? ArrayElement<T[KA]> : number>
    } : never
}


Thank you for your suggestion. Unfortunately, it doesn’t seem to work, everything turns into any type or maybe i missing something ?

@jon I have checked the "playground" link and its build without any error

The playground provided above has no errors and compiles successfully. The problem lies with the typing. The only non-viable solution is to use as const everywhere. Therefore, I am looking for an alternative to this issue. Your suggestion does not cause any errors, but all the types become any and not fix the lines with tags .
if you put any everywhere yes the app with compile
